# ¿Cómo desplegar una página html desde otra página htm, pasándole un parámetro, esto bajo Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

En Jquery, grabo una la información de una cotización en la base de datos y luego despliego en pantalla un mensaje "Desea imprimir la cotización  ", si la respuesta es "Sí", entonces se debe abrir otra ventana, la cual recibe un parámetro que le sirve para traer la información grabada en la base de datos, dibujar la cotización en dicha pantalla y con un botón en esta ventana, generar el pdf.

De todo estos pasos, ya tengo la forma de grabar la información de la cotización en la base de datos; también tengo la forma de buscar en la base de datos la información grabada y dibujar la cotización. Lo que no sé es cómo invocar la nueva ventana, pasándole el parámetro que utilizará para hacer la búsqueda en la BD.

Cualquier aporte, les estaré muy agradecido.

Añado lo siguiente:

Logré invocar la nueva página con la información que se dibuja, usando lo siguiente:

```
document.location.href = "index1.php?parametro1=" + parametro1 +"&";
```

El problema que me queda es que se despliega en la misma ventana desde la cual se está invocando, perdiéndose la vista de la información que estaba desplegada.

Lo que necesito es que se despliegue en una nueva ventana independiente de la ventana desde donde se está invocando; esa típica ventana tipo marco que se despliega cuando mandamos a imprimir algo.

La porción del archivo php que hace la invocación es la siguiente:

```
            }else if(tipomov=="Cotizacion")
                    {                           
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "grabar_venta.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: cadena,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(respuesta)
                            {                               
                                $.dialogbox(
                                {
                                    type:'msg',
                                    title:'Impresión',
                                    content:'Desea imprimir el documento?',
                                    closeBtn:true,
                                    btn:['Aceptar','Cancelar'],
                                    call:[
                                        function()
                                        {                       
                                            document.location.href = "index1.php?respuesta=" + respuesta +"&";
                                        },
                                        function()
                                        {                                       
                                            $.dialogbox.close();
                                            $('#frmregistrar')[0].reset();  
                                            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                                                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                                            }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());   
                                            eliminaFilas();
                                        }
                                    ]
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }else if(tipomov=="Venta")
                    {
```

El archivo que se invoca index1.php es:

```
<?php  
$v1 = $_GET['respuesta'];
 function busca_datos($v)  
 {  
 //LOGICA DE LA FUNCION QUE BUSCA LO DATOS
      return $output;  
 }  
 if(isset($_POST["create_pdf"]))  
 {  
      require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); 
      $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
      $obj_pdf->SetTitle("Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP");  
      $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
      $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
      $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
      $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
      $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
      $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
      $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
      $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
      $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);  
      $obj_pdf->AddPage();  
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  
      <h3 align="center">Export HTML Table data to PDF using TCPDF in PHP</h3><br /><br />  
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">  
           <tr>  
              <th>ID</th>  
              <th>Name</th>  
              <th>Gender</th>  
              <th>Designation</th>
              <th>Age</th>
           </tr>
      ';  
      $content .= busca_datos($v1);  

      $content .= '</table>';  
      //echo $content;
      $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      //$obj_pdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
      $serial='123';
      //$nombre='Hugo Sanzana_'.$serial.'_'.date("d-m-Y-h:i:s");
      $nombre='Hugo Sanzana_'.$serial.'_'.date("d-m-Y H-i-s");
      $obj_pdf->Output($nombre, 'I');
 }   
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Exportando a PDF desde PHP</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">            
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Exportando a PDF desde PHP usando TCPDF en PHP</h3><br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th>ID</th>  
                               <th>Name</th>  
                               <th>Gender</th>  
                               <th>Designation</th>
                               <th>Age</th>
                               <!--<th width="10%">Age</th> -->
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     echo busca_datos($v1);  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                     <br />  
                     <form method="post">  
                          <input type="submit" name="create_pdf" class="btn btn-danger" value="Crear PDF" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

En estos momento puedo ejecutar correctamente la funcionalidad, el único problema es que index1.php se despliega en la misma pantalla donde es invocado; lo que necesito es que se despliegue en una nueva pantalla independiente de la pantalla desde donde se invocó.

Comment: Intenta hacerlo con [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open), aunque dependiendo de como has hecho tu `html`, podrias usar directamente un [`anchor`  con `target _blank`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu sugerencia. La instrucción windows.open() permite incluir un parámetro para pasárselo a la página que se abrirá?

Comment: Dependiendo de cuantos datos necesitas enviar, siempre puedes enviarlos por `GET`, por ejemplo, `index1.php?param1=x1&param2=x2`, donde `paramN` puede ser cualquier palabra y `xN`, cualquier cadena.

Comment: Correcto, pues como ves, en el php donde hago la invocación, tengo:

document.location.href = "index1.php?respuesta=" + respuesta +"&";

y en el php invocado tengo:

$v1 = $_GET['respuesta'];

Con esto tengo solucionado el problema de pasar un parametro a la pagina invocada. El problema es que la página index1.php se despliega en la misma ventana desde donde es llamada y ese comportamiento está incorrecto, pues se requiere que se mantenga a la vista la información de la pantalla original.
El tema ya no es invocar la página y pasar el parámetro, sino el despliegue en otra ventana.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos Gallardo por tus sugerencias. Ya logré solucionarlo; la forma la puse al final de la pregunta inicial.

Comment: @JuncoFuerte Comenta tu solución como respuesta a tu pregunta, saludos

Answer (score 4):

Solucioné el problema y por si a alguien le puede servir, dejo la forma que utilicé:

Cambié:

```
document.location.href = "index1.php?respuesta=" + respuesta +"&";
```

Por:

```
window.open("index1.php?respuesta=" + respuesta, "", "location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,width=800,height=400");
```

Con eso, ya funciona todo como lo requería. Muchas gracias.